# Using expressjs and express-generator, where in bin/www does it call app.js?

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I followed the installation for express-generator properly I think. I see in the package.json that the starting script is bin/www. I looked through bin/www and can't find where that script calls my script 'app.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `npm start`, it reads **package.json** file and execute `start` in scripts tag.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

So, it executes `node ./bin/www` in which you must have `var app = require('../app');` which loads the **app.js** dependency.

And following lines creates the http server from `app.js` and start listening at given port

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Disclaimer: Above observation is based on default `express myapp` app.